# Name for a phrase, whose words communicate the similar meaning (fluid liquid, white bleach)

Tags: single-word-requests

How would you call this kind of lexical errors, when two words of a phrase communicate generally similar meaning?

- fluid liquid
- sunny sun
- white bleach
- decorative ornament
- sorrowful misery

Comment: Bleach is often colourless (not white). Was it included in the list intentionally?

Comment: This is tautology in the case of 'sorrowful misery' (saying the same thing twice over), pleonasm in general (using superfluous words, eg 'He saw it with his eyes.'). But redundancy is by no means always wrong.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Much obliged!